# DD4T & Broker API gives "Cannot open connection" error?

Tags: 2011, dd4t

I'm getting the error listed below from a DD4T-enabled site I'm trying to work.  I've verifed my DB connection info & it looks correct.  Is this a license issue?  Is the "Cannot open connection" error really causing this?

```
    2013-09-10 14:46:06,534 ERROR SessionsCleanerMonitor - Could not perform sessions clean-up. Will retry in 120000 milliseconds.
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:614) ~[hibernate-entitymanager.jar:3.4.0.GA]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:76) ~[hibernate-entitymanager.jar:3.4.0.GA]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPABaseDAO.executeQueryListResult(JPABaseDAO.java:266) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPABaseDAO.executeQueryListResult(JPABaseDAO.java:234) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPABaseDAO.executeQueryListResult(JPABaseDAO.java:217) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.session.persistence.JPAPreviewSessionDAO.getExpiredSessions(JPAPreviewSessionDAO.java:84) ~[cd_session.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.session.SessionServiceImpl.getExpiredSessions(SessionServiceImpl.java:75) ~[cd_session.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.session.SessionManagerImpl.performCleanup(SessionManagerImpl.java:227) ~[cd_session.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.session.SessionsCleanerMonitor.run(SessionsCleanerMonitor.java:54) ~[cd_session.jar:na]
```

Comment: You most likely have the sessionwrapper enabled which is only need if you are using XPM/UI 2012. Try commenting out the session wrapper in your storage conf.

Comment: I made some changes & now I am getting a "Page Not Found" error from the base.Page(pageId) message.  It looks like the page is in tridion & has the View metadata item filled in.  How do I determine the issue with this error?

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, the message "Cannot open connection" is usually accurate: the database server cannot be reached. Have you tried to connect (e.g. using telnet) to the specified server & port from the machine which runs the web application? Be aware that with DD4T, this could well be the PC of the individual developer!

Comment: For MSSQL connections, here's one way to check them http://www.dominic.cronin.nl/weblog/smoke-testing-my-tridion-database-connections

Answer (score 2):

The content delivery license is specific to a machine. Steps to ensure valid installation is given [HERE](http://kb.sdl.com/?portalid=23&articleid=3516#tab%3ahomeTab%3acrumb:7%3aartId:3516).

Can you also check connectivity from content delivery machine to the database server using ***telnet databaseserver port***?

If the database connectivity and authentication works (as you have highlighted above), this looks to be more of an issue with your storage configuration. I suspect that you are modifying the wrapper for SessionPreview. Can you update your question with the storage configuration settings from cd_storage.xml?